# Can I play an audio (or audio/video) file from a DLL written in C++?

Tags: audio, dll, windows-7

We want to play audio (and video) files from a DLL.  RenderSharedEvent/TimerDriven works, but for a number of reasons we prefer to do playback at a higher level- Media Foundation, or even the deprecated MediaPlay or waveOut functions would work.  However, so far I'm not seeing the callbacks, and they seem to be a critical part of the process.

Is that because they don't work from a DLL, or is there something I'm missing?  I remember it used to be impossible to use waveOut from a DLL, but I assumed the new frameworks would support a DLL.

Comment: DirectSound is technically not maintained by Microsoft anymore, but it can still play wave audio files without any problems, and you can find it with a quick Google search.

Comment: I'll go to DS if I need to, but I would like to know if there's a way to use MFPlay or MediaFoundation from a DLL.  Otherwise I have to re-write a pile of code.